# Evaluate if a linear system of equations has exactly one solution, infinitely many solutions or no solutions based on coefficient value

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations

I want to know for which values of constant a the following system of equations has exactly one solution, infinitely many solutions or no solution:

$x + y + z = 0$

$x + 2y + az = 1$

$x + ay + 2z = -1$

My approach to solving this problem was to construct an augmented matrix, then reducing it. I end up with the following:

$\left[
    \begin{array}{ccc|c}
        1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 & \frac{-1}{(a - 2)}\\
        0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{1}{(a - 2)}
    \end{array}
\right]$

What I am now struggling with is how to interpret this. My reasoning is as follows:

From the last row, I end up with $1 = \frac{1}{(a - 2)}~$.

Thus, for $a  = 2$, there should be no solution or infinitely many solutions as it would result in division by $0$.

If $a \neq 2$, there should be exactly one solution.

Is this correct? Would there be a more appropriate way to determine the value of constant $a$ such that it satisfies these conditions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a general rule, you will find it helpful to evaluate the determinant of the matrix of coefficients and identify the value(s) of $a$ for which this determinant is zero.

The determinant works out to be $$2a-a^2$$

So there is a unique solution provided $a\neq2, a\neq0$.

When $a=2$ the equations are evidently inconsistent: the second and third equations are parallel and distinct planes, so there is no solution.

However, when $a=0$ the equations are linearly dependent: the first equation may be obtained by adding the second and third. This means that the planes intersect in a common line, so there are infinitely many solutions. You can solve any two of these equations and obtain the line of intersection.

You can check for yourself, but I got $$\underline{r}=\left(\begin{matrix}-1\\1\\0\end{matrix}\right)+\lambda\left(\begin{matrix}-2\\1\\1\end{matrix}\right)$$

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer and solution, this is exactly what I was looking for and it is the same conclusion I reached when evaluating the determinant of the matrix. 

Just to clarify regarding the case of a = 2 - I presume it is not possible to have both no solutions and infinitely many solutions when the equations are indeed inconsistent? The reason for asking is that I seemed to find signs of it being the case when evaluating the reduced row echelon form.

Comment: If the equations are inconsistent then there can be no solutions which satisfy all three equations. In your example when $a=2$ the two parallel planes intersect with the first plane in two separate but parallel lines, so there are no values satisfying all three equations. In the case where $a=0$ all three planes intersect on one line forming a sheaf. Any points on that line satisfy all three equations so there are infinitely many solutions.

Comment: That does make sense, thanks for the clarification!